# Partial database shortcut in SSDT

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-data-tools

I'm assuming this is not possible but asking just in case.  I have two database projects in my Visual Studio 2013 solution and Database Y mostly just has shortcuts to tables in Database X.  Everything worked great until I added partitioning to the definition of Table A in Database X.  Since I deploy Database X to SQL Server 2012 Enterprise and deploy Database Y to SQL Server 2012 Standard, and partitioning is not allowed in Standard, the latter deployment fails.

Is there a way to tell the database project for Database Y to ignore the partitioning stuff?  Any other ideas on how to keep the tables in sync without using a shortcut?

UPDATE: Here is the error.

> Creating [PartitionByReportFileID]... (75,1): SQL72014: .Net SqlClient
>   Data Provider: Msg 7736, Level 16, State 1, Line 2 Partition function
>   can only be created in Enterprise edition of SQL Server. Only
>   Enterprise edition of SQL Server supports partitioning. (74,0):
>   SQL72045: Script execution error.  The executed script: CREATE
>   PARTITION FUNCTION PartitionByReportFileID
>       AS RANGE RIGHT
>       FOR VALUES (90000000, 120000000, 140000000, 160000000, 180000000, 200000000, 220000000, 240000000, 260000000, 280000000, 300000000,
>   320000000, 340000000, 360000000, 380000000, 400000000, 420000000,
>   440000000, 460000000, 480000000, 500000000, 520000000, 540000000,
>   560000000, 580000000, 600000000);
>
> An error occurred while the batch was being executed.

Comment: What do you mean by "shortcut", exactly - cross-database view, or synonym? Neither of them in Standard that points to Enterprise should stop working because of partitioning of their underlying tables, afaik.

Comment: I don't know what it's called when you Add->Existing Item and point to a separate project. Partitioning is not allowed in Standard Edition so the deployment fails when the script tries to run in SQL Server.

Comment: It's nothing. Just tried to do that and VS 2012 simply copies the file from its original location to a designated folder. No kind of linking or shortcutting of any kind seem to be established. Don't think 2013 behaves any differently from this.

Answer (score 1):

**UPD:** Well, it's possible, though you probably won't like the approach.

Indeed, SSDT includes partition-related stuff into the deployment script no matter how hard one tries not to allow it. The other way is to create an empty database and then perform a schema compare between the project (source) and that database (target). In the schema compare settings, make sure 2 checks are set on the General tab:

- Ignore object placement on partition schemes
- Ignore partition schemes

This works in SSDT 2012, verified. From this point on, you can either run an update directly, or generate script and then use it for deployment, with only minor modifications (such as adding the database (re)creation part from the standard deployment script, if needed).

The only drawback with this approach is that previously partitioned tables appear on default filegroup, which is usually `PRIMARY` unless you change it. That, and post-deployment script functionality isn't included, afaik (assuming you have one, of course).

Comment: You would think that would work, wouldn't you? For reasons I can't explain the error does not go away. I gave you 1UP because it's a good answer even though it didn't help me in my current situation.

Comment: @influent, after you have excluded all the partitioning stuff from deployment / schema compare, the piece of code that triggers the error - how it looks like? What it is, exactly? Can you update your post with it?